# How to reset state variables to its initial state after component re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am writing a full stack web application to register a user. I have state variables to reflect the back-end errors, which are then used in the jsx code. I re-render the component whenever the `alerts` change (which are app-level state managed by redux whose content are generated by the backend). The problem I am facing is that, when the first time I don't enter the required info and hit submit, I display the errors successfully below the corresponding wrongly entered field for 1 second before dispatching a clear alert action, and although `alerts` state are updated according to redux devtool, the error message would still be there after 1 s in the component. I think the problem is that I need to reset the local state variable that corresponds to the field that was cleared, but I am not sure how to implement that. The errors are captured in `errorsData` state variable below. Here is my component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerUser } from '../../actions/auth';

const Register = ({ setAlert, alerts, registerUser }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    password2: '',
  });
  const [errorsData, setErrorsData] = useState({
    nameErr: '',
    emailErr: '',
    passwordErr: '',
  });

  const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData;
  const { nameErr, emailErr, passwordErr } = errorsData;

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleOnSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      console.log('Passwords do not match');
    } else {
      registerUser({ name, email, password });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    alerts.forEach((alert) => {
      if (alert.errField === 'name') {
        setErrorsData({ ...errorsData, nameErr: alert.msg });
      }
      if (alert.errField === 'email') {
        setErrorsData({ ...errorsData, emailErr: alert.msg });
      }
      if (alert.errField === 'password') {
        setErrorsData({ ...errorsData, passwordErr: alert.msg });
      }
    });
  }, [alerts]);

  return (
    <form className='form' onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
      <div className='input-field'>
        <label htmlFor='name'>Name</label>
        <input
          type='text'
          name='name'
          value={name}
          id='name'
          placeholder='Enter your name'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
        <small className='error error--name'>{nameErr}</small>
      </div>
      <div className='input-field'>
        <label htmlFor='email'>Email</label>
        <input
          type='email'
          name='email'
          value={email}
          id='email'
          placeholder='Enter a valid email'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
        <small className='error error--email'>{emailErr}</small>
      </div>
      <div className='input-field'>
        <label htmlFor='password'>Passwrod</label>
        <input
          type='password'
          name='password'
          value={password}
          id='password'
          placeholder='Enter password'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
        <small className='error error--password'>{passwordErr}</small>
      </div>
      <div className='input-field'>
        <label htmlFor='password2'>Confirm password</label>
        <input
          type='password'
          name='password2'
          value={password2}
          id='password2'
          placeholder='Confirm password'
          onChange={handleOnChange}
        />
      </div>
      <input className='submit' type='submit' value='Submit' />
    </form>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  alerts: state.alert,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setAlert, registerUser })(Register);
```

Comment: If you're using redux inside a functional component, why don't you directly use your redux error state inside your component with the `useSelector` hook from `react-redux`?

Comment: Also, you're importing `connect` from `react-redux` inside a functional component, which are incompatible; either your component is set up incorrectly or you're not showing the proper code

Comment: I am not aware of that as I am new to both react and redux. I actually modified a code where alerts are displayed in a separate component, but because I want to display errors below each field rather than on the top of the screen, I decided to use `alerts` inside `Register` component.

Comment: @rantao why `connect` is not compatible with functional component? I am following some materials, and this seems to be used all the time to use app-level state in functional components.

Comment: Its fine to pass `alerts` as props like that, but if you're going to update your redux store properly inside your functional component, you'll have to use the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hooks  instead of `connect` See https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks for more information

Comment: `connect` is used for class components only

Answer (score 0):

Your component is setup incorrectly because you are trying to use `connect` with functional components when you must be using `useDispatch` and `useTypedSelector` for redux with functional components. Instead you should do something like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

/* Hooks */
**import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";**

/* Actions */
import { registerUser } from "../../actions/auth";
import { setAlert } from "../../actions/alert";

const Register = () => {
    // Hooks
    **const dispatch = useDispatch();**

    // Store
    **const alerts = useSelector(state => state.alert);**

    // Local state
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        password2: "",
    });
    const [errorsData, setErrorsData] = useState({
        nameErr: "",
        emailErr: "",
        passwordErr: "",
    });

    const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData;
    const { nameErr, emailErr, passwordErr } = errorsData;

    // Event handlers
    const handleOnChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const handleOnSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (password !== password2) console.log("Passwords do not match");
        else dispatch(registerUser({ name, email, password }));
    };

    // Effects
    useEffect(() => {
        alerts.forEach(alert => {
            switch(alert.errField) {
                case "name":
                    setErrorsData({ ...errorsData, nameErr: alert.msg });
                    break;
                case "email":
                    setErrorsData({ ...errorsData, emailErr: alert.msg });
                    break;
                case "password":
                    setErrorsData({ ...errorsData, passwordErr: alert.msg });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            };
        });
    }, [alerts, errorsData]);

    // Rendering
    return (
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={name}
                    id="name"
                    placeholder="Enter your name"
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
                <small className="error error--name">{nameErr}</small>
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={email}
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Enter a valid email"
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
                <small className="error error--email">{emailErr}</small>
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="password">Passwrod</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    value={password}
                    id="password"
                    placeholder="Enter password"
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
                <small className="error error--password">{passwordErr}</small>
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
                <label htmlFor="password2">Confirm password</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password2"
                    value={password2}
                    id="password2"
                    placeholder="Confirm password"
                    onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
            </div>
            <input className="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    );
};

**export default Register;**
```

Major changes are highlighted.